# Как закрыть программу без появления дополнительных окон

Tags: vbscript

Возникла новая проблема с программой из старого вопроса. Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии программы на крестик она действительно закрывалась, вместо того, чтобы выдавать окно: "ОТ 1 ДО 13!", желательно без подключения дополнительных библиотек и прочего, просто vbscript код, заранее спасибо!

Код (с учётом прошлых поправок):

```
x = inputbox("Введите число от 1 до 13:")
if (x > 13) or (x < 1) then
msgbox "ОТ 1 ДО 13!", 16, "Ошибка"
else
msgbox "Вау, твоё число - " & x, 48, "Ы"
end if
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто добавьте проверку на пустую строку

```
x = inputbox("Введите число от 1 до 13:")
if x<>"" then
    if (x > 13) or (x < 1) then
        msgbox "ОТ 1 ДО 13!", 16, "Ошибка"
    else
        msgbox "Вау, твоё число - " & x, 48, "Ы"
    end if
end if
```